# Guidelines for running tv cables behind walls for an HD TV

Tags: appliances, mounting

My in-laws want to mount a new TV on the wall and have asked their contractors (they are in the middle of a renovation) to open a hole above their gas burning fireplace for routing cables to/from the TV. The contractors opened up a hole to the right of center.

Are there guidelines or special tricks for placing the hole so that they would work with all TV mounts so that the mount can be centered above the fireplace without interfering with the hole?

Or do I have to first buy the TV mount and TV to figure out the best placement for the hole? (In my case since they've already opened up a hole I guess I would have to buy mounts that would work with the hole)

Do manufacturers of mounts have any special specs that they design to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The placement of the hole is not critical so long as it will be behind the tv panel. Obviously a hole immediately under a structural component of the mount might be a problem.

The mount is more critical than the hole. Buy the type of mount you need and see where it lands in relation to the hole. There may be no conflict. If there is, covering the old hole and making a new one is not hard.

A bigger issue is how you terminate the wires and cables.  Are you bringing power to an outlet immediately behind the tv? If so, you need an appropriately mounted electrical outlet box. Additionally, a hole may slightly compromise insulation and allow a draft, so it is a good idea to have a box and a cover plate for the cables even if the are not power cables.

There are specialty outlet [boxes](http://www.av-express.com/AV-Catalog/Recessed-TV-Boxes/DataComm-Electronics-45-0031-WH-Recessed-Low-Voltage-Media-Plate-w-Duplex-Receptacle-White) with low voltage media connectors or access holes. You should determine the placement of this after the mount is in place on the wall.

[image: media box]